# UITableViewCell Looks Correct on Simulator but is Off-Center on Device

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nslayoutconstraint

I have created a custom UITableViewCell with its own XIB and subclass.

When I view the UITableView on my iOS Simulator, the cells appear as expected.

But when I run this same code on a physical device (have tried on several devices), the cells appear far off-center.

I am using NSLayoutConstraints in Interface Builder to set this all up.

Please let me know if you have any idea what might be the problem here.

[image: simulator]

[image: device]

Comment: Are you running it on the same device type on simulator and physical device, e.g. both iPhon 5s!? Have you setup the constraints in the correct size classes? Are you changing any layout via code?

Comment: I have run it on iPhone 5S, 6, and 6 Plus simulators. I have run it on physical 5S and 6. In all these cases, it looks correct on the simulator and incorrect on the devices. I am not doing anything to the layout outside of IB.

Comment: It seems to be a problem with the custom UITableViewCell, I was able to import a different custom UITableViewCell and it aligned correctly. Will update when/if I find the source of the problem.

Comment: Trailing & leading edge constraints don't play well with others, check those.